# How do I make three tables share the same field as primary key in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do make my three tables share the same "part_no" field as primary key?  I need to access "part_no" with three different tables.  How?  Do they have to be the same name?

```
 TABLE NAME:  cartons_current
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | Column     |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | part_no    | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
 | qty        | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
 | qty_time   | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+

 TABLE NAME:  cartons_add
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | Column     |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | part_no    | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
 | add_qty    | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
 | add_time   | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+

 TABLE NAME:  cartons_pull
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | Column     |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | part_no    | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
 | pull_qty   | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
 | pull_time  | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: If all fields have the same primary key, this should really all be in one table.

Comment: Johan, that is very frequently not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the records that share a primary key use the following select.

```
SELECT cc.part_no, cc.qty, cc.qty_time
                 , ca.add_qty as qty_added, ca.add_time as time_added
                 , cp.pull_qty as qty_pulled, cp.pull_time as time_pulled
FROM cartons_current cc
INNER JOIN cartons_add ca ON (ca.part_no = cc.part_no)
INNER JOIN cartons_pull cp ON (cp.part_no = cc.part_no)
WHERE cc.part_no = '124'
```

Comment: Do I add this to the root database?

Comment: @Erik, It's just a query, you call it using php, C# or whatever frontend you use and the wanted result will come out.